# Pass variable to dialog in Microsoft BotBuilder C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

I'm trying to build my bot using this [example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt).

The flow now:

1. User writes something `foo`.
2. Bot enters dialog...

I'm stuck on getting user's first message `foo` inside the [dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt/Dialogs/UserProfileDialog.cs).

Comment: You should show us your code, if you want us to help you

Comment: Hi, Olli, my code gone not far from example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user input from the `turnContext` like this:

```
string userInput = turnContext.Context.Activity.Text
```

Example:

```
 public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
 {
     string userInput = turnContext.Activity.Text;
 }
```

As for passing a variable to **UserProfileDialog**, you can do it in the following way:

```
await innerDc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(DialogFlowDialog), userInput );
```

**BeginDialogAsync** accepts an **optional argument** (**Object**) to pass to the dialog being started.

In your **UserProfileDialog**, you can get that argument from the **stepContext**

Example:

```
 private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> TransportStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string userInput = string.Empty;

            // Options contains the information the waterfall dialog was called with
            if (stepContext.Options != null)
            {
                userInput = stepContext.Options.ToString();
            }
        }
```

If you want to get the first message the user sends, you can always get it from the context, if you are using the **05.multi-turn-prompt** you can get it this way inside your **UserProfileDialog**

```
   private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> TransportStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // this contains the text message the user sent
            string userInput = stepContext.Context.Activity.Text;
            // WaterfallStep always finishes with the end of the Waterfall or with another dialog; here it is a Prompt Dialog.
            // Running a prompt here means the next WaterfallStep will be run when the users response is received.
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt),
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter your mode of transport."),
                    Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(new List<string> { "Car", "Bus", "Bicycle" }),
                }, cancellationToken);
        }
```

or like this inside your **DialogBot**

```
  public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {

            // this contains the text message the user sent
            string userInput = turnContext.Activity.Text;

            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

            // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
            await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean `string userInput = turnContext.Activity.Text;`? So I add that in [DialogBot.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt/Bots/DialogBot.cs), but how can I get this variable in [UserProfileDialog.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt/Dialogs/UserProfileDialog.cs)?

Comment: @Esbarro check my Edited response, if that's what you needed please mark it as answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. Didn't make it yet, having issues with using `innerDc`, "CS0103 C# The name does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Thank you Marс! I am absolutely sure that I did just that before asking the question, but the variable returned an empty string in the first step for some reason. But now it works. Thank you for your time and participation!